# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constrain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm kind of new to scripting in SQL and I have encountered an error in one of my scripts.
The problematic section is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.WorkspaceSettings
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
        ReportColorRGB1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '61,105,138' ,
    ReportColorRGB2 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '180,210,121' 
)

GO

ALTER TABLE Workspace ADD WorkspaceSettingsId int NOT NULL default 1;

GO
ALTER TABLE Workspace
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_WorkspaceSettings_Workspace
FOREIGN KEY (WorkspaceSettingsId)
REFERENCES WorkspaceSettings(Id);
GO
```

And receive the following error message:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_WorkspaceSettings_Workspace". The conflict occurred in database "ClearRisk2_0", table "dbo.WorkspaceSettings", column 'Id'.

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default value of 1 that you've specified for the `Workspace.WorkspaceSettingsId` column does not yet exist in your `WorkspaceSettings` table, hence the FK violation.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following phrase after ALter table sattement:

```
with nocheck
```

So, it will be:

```
Use Database_name

Go
    ALTER TABLE ResultScan with nocheck
      ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ResultScan_ListVM FOREIGN KEY (TypeAnVirus)     
      REFERENCES ListVM (Id)     
      ON DELETE CASCADE    
      ON UPDATE CASCADE    
   ;    
  GO
```

Comment: It is important to explain what `no check` does here.  Most likely this won't address the problem - - Just hide it and cause bigger problems later.